# Multiple action 'on' events in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to have an element be able to be clicked on by both touchscreens, and clicking, through the events `touchStart` and `click`.

How can I get both of these events connected to one Ember view?

I have tried:

`{{action "itsClicked" on="click touchMove"}}`

`{{action "itsClicked" on="click, touchMove"}}`

`{{action "itsClicked" on="click"}} {{action "itsClicked" on="touchMove"}}`

Comment: ember.js is not sproutcore anymore. You should use the emberjs tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not supported. But there is an open issue about this, see [#569](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/569) in the GitHub issue tracker. You should add a comment.

The suggested solution from the GitHub issue is to use a custom view, something like this:

```js
Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(evt) {
        this.fire('itsClicked', evt);
    },
    touchMove: function() {
        this.fire('itsClicked', evt);
    },
    itsClicked: function(e) {
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: Wow that's annoying. I can understand some of the things they're trying to prevent in the #569 conversation but there should be a very simple syntax that captures both mouse clicks and touchscreen touches as they will point to the same interaction and it just doesn't seem there is a downside. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple actions are not supported - this forces you separate your code by creating components (or views).

However, you can easily solve the click/touch issue for your application by creating a custom event:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    customEvents: {touchend: "click"}
});
```

This means all your "click" events will fire when touched